# on click checkbox set input attr

Tags: jquery, attr, toggleclass

html form with 4 columns the first 2 columns are the sizes inside input boxes with disabled ='disabled', when they click radio button to select a size a checkbox appears, when they click that checkbox I would like to change the class and disabled attr of the inputs on that table row to allow them to edit the input box

```
<table width="388" border="1" id="product1">
<tr>
<td width="100">Width</td>
<td width="100">Height</td>
<td width="48">Price</td>
<td width="65">Select</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" disabled='disabled'value="200"/><span> CMS</span></td>
<td><input disabled='disabled'type="text" value="500"/><span> CMS</span></td>
<td>£50.00</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="product1" value="size1" /> Customise<input     type="checkbox"   name="custom[size1]" class="custombox" value="1"/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
<td>200</td>
<td>1000</td>
<td>£100.00</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="product1" value="size2" /> Customise<input         disabled='disabled' type="checkbox" name="custom[size2]" class="custombox" value="1"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>200</td>
<td>1500</td>
<td>£150</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="product1" value="size3" /> Customise<input     type="checkbox" name="custom[size3]" class="custombox" value="1"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table width="288" border="1" id="product2">
<tr>
<td width="72">Width</td>
<td width="75">Height</td>
<td width="48">Price</td>
<td width="65">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
<td>200</td>
<td>500</td>
<td>£50.00</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="product2" value="size1" /> Customise<input     type="checkbox" name="custom[size1]" class="custombox" value="1"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>200</td>
<td>1000</td>
<td>£100.00</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="product2" value="size2" /> Customise<input     type="checkbox" name="custom[size2]" class="custombox" value="1"/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
<td>200</td>
<td>1500</td>
<td>£150</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="product2" value="size3" /> Customise<input type="checkbox" name="custom[size3]" class="custombox" value="1"/></td>
 </tr>
<table>
```

CSS

```
input[type=checkbox] {
display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox].shown {
display: inline;
}

input .edit{
border:1px solid red;
}
input[disabled='disabled'] {  
border:0px;
width:60px;
padding:5px;
float:left;
background:#fff;
}

span{float:left; width:30px; padding:5px;}
```

Jquery

```
 $("body :checkbox").hide();

// The most obvious way is to set radio-button click handlers for each table separatly:
$("#product1 :radio").click(function() {
$("#product1 :checkbox").hide();
  $("#product1 .cbox").hide();
$(this).parent().children(":checkbox").show();
  $(this).parent().children(".cbox").show();
});

$("#product2 :radio").click(function() {
$("#product2 :checkbox").hide();
    $("#product2 .cbox").hide();
$(this).parent().children(":checkbox").show();
$(this).parent().children(".cbox").show();
});
```

This is what I thought but its not working

```
$("#product1 :checkbox").click(function(){
$(this).parent("tr").children("td :input").attr('disabled','');
$(this).parent("tr").children("td :input").toggleClass(edit);
});

$("#product2 :checkbox").click(function(){
$(this).parent("tr").children("td :input").attr('disabled','');
$(this).parent("tr").children("td :input").toggleClass(edit);
});
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplified question with answer is here [set attr of inputs on this row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701604/set-attr-of-inputs-on-this-row) in case anyone else has this issue

Comment: Simplified question with answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701604/set-attr-of-inputs-on-this-row in case anyone else has this issue

Answer (score 0):

According to [jQuery's FAQ](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_disable.2Fenable_a_form_element.3F) you could use

```
$('#x').attr('disabled', false);
//or
$("#x").removeAttr('disabled');
```

Take note though your `.parent("tr")` is probably not the best idea as it could be ambiguous. Be more specific (give classes or something).

Comment: tried this but its not working      $(this).parent().children(".ed:input").attr('disabled', false);                    I am a complete beginner with jquery so i really dont understand how the parent() and children() work

Comment: I had a look at your simplified question. Have a look at the jQuery examples and documentation. If you spend some time with it you'll quickly figure it out.