# set attr of inputs on this row

Tags: jquery

I have a table with 3 rows

```
 <table id="table1">
 <tr>
 <td><input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="200"/></td>
 <td><input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="300"/></td>
 <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
 <tr>
 <tr>
 <td><input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="400"/></td>
 <td><input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="600"/></td>
 <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
 <tr>
 </table>
```

Jquery when someone clicks the checkbox i would like to change the attr of the 2 inputs on that row and make them editable but if someone clicks the checkbox on another row the previously enabled input must be disabled and the new one enabled

This is what i thought but it doesnt work

```
   $("#table1 :checkbox").click(function(){
   $(this).parent(":input[type='text']").attr('disabled',false);

   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parent(":input[type='text']")` says "give me the parent node if it is an input element with the type `text`. This obviously isn't what you want!  You need to use `find`:

```
$("#table1 :checkbox").click(function(){
    $(this)
       .closest('tr') // find the parent row
           .find(":input[type='text']") // find text elements in that row
               .attr('disabled',false) // enable them
           .end() // go back to the row
           .siblings() // get its siblings
               .find(":input[type='text']") // find text elements in those rows
                   .attr('disabled',true); // disable them
});
```

Comment: Thanks your explanation was very easy to understand, Thanks for helping out, to you and all other answerers

Comment: A bit late, but this code behaves erratically for me -  Rows are disabled and enabled inappropriately (tried JQuery 1.4, and 1.6)

Answer (score 1):

You can watch watch for changes to all of your checkboxes, which will fire on both selections and deselections. If selected we can set the `disabled` attribute to an empty string in order to "enable", and if deselected to "disabled" in order to re-disable the inputs:

```
$('#table1 :checkbox').change(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="text"]').attr('disabled',
        this.checked ? '' : 'disabled'
    );
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/marcuswhybrow/8WtvK/

Comment: I had a similar situation and was able to get this to do what I needed. Thanks, for the tip, note that you need to change .attr to .prop for JQuery 1.6 or later.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#table1 input:checkbox').click(function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');

    row.find('input:text').attr('disabled', false);
    row.siblings().find('input:text').attr('disabled', true);
});
```

***Live demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/buAmd/

I used radio boxes in the demo since both boxes cannot be checked at the same time.